# How to use multiple extract methods for raster NA values

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I'm quite new to r and coding and I'd appreciate any help please.

I have two data sets:
A raster object with degree heating weeks (a remotely sensed measure of cumulative sea surface temperature).
A set of coordinates recording where coral bleaching occurred.

I have successfully extracted the DHW values at each coordinate using the following:
`raster::extract(mydata, coords, method="simple")`

However, there are many NA values. I believe that this is because many coordinates are close to the coast and occupy predominantly land-filled pixels.

I would like to use `methods="bilinear"` to interpolate values for the NA cells and `methods="simple"` for the non-NA cells. I would like the output to be one object.

I wrote the following function:

`````
  if(is.na(dhw_raster[])){
    raster::extract(dhw_raster, coords, method="bilinear")
  } else {
    raster::extract(dhw_raster, coords, method="simple")
  }
}````




However, it returns only the method="simple" values, and this warning:

In if (is.na(dhw_raster[])) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Any advice would be great :)
`````

Comment: Please post the first rows of your datasets using the `dput` function

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something like this

```
x <- raster::extract(mydata, coords, method="simple")
y <- raster::extract(mydata, coords, method="bilinear")
```

And now replace the missing values in `x` with the values in `y` (and then use `x`)

```
i <- is.na(x)
x[i] <- y[i]
```